# F-String round float to either 0 or 1 decimals, and how much logic inside an f-string is OK?

Tags: python, python-3.6, f-string

I have a bunch of floating point numbers that are either x.0 or x.5 and if they are x.0 I want no decimal points displayed, and if they are x.5 I want one decimal point displayed.

I have come up with a one-liner that does the job:

```
f'{x:+.{int(bool(x % 1))}f}'
```

Where `int(bool(x % 1))` will always be 0 or 1 depending on whether modulo yields a remainder.

This works fine because of the nature of my float inputs, but it got me thinking, what if my inputs weren't so neat? For example the above one-liner with `10.01` as an input returns `10.0`. My temptation is to first round the float to the desired precision:

```
f'{x:+.{int(bool(round(x, 1) % 1))}f}'
```

If there wasn't already a lot going on inside the `f-string` in my first example, there is now.

To be clear about my question:

Firstly, is my first method the 'right' way to go about what I'm actually trying to achieve given my real-world inputs?

Secondly, how about in the case of the hypothetical problem and my second example?

Thirdly, I'd like to canvas opinion from the community regarding where use of `f-string` crosses the line to abuse. As an example of how one might be tempted to pack a lot of stuff into the `f-string`, how about something like this to get a list of strings containing numbers to sort alphabetically:

```
f"String with number:{' ' if x >= 1000 else '  ' if x >= 100 else '   ' if x >= 10 else '    '}{x:+.{int(bool(round(x, 1) % 1))}f}"
```

So I hope tying this question about overuse of `f-string` in with my rounding question doesn't cause the overall question to be too vague, but these are two issues that I'm considering together. I suppose the 'neatness' of `f-string` can provide a temptation to shoehorn everything into one-liners.

Comment: My personal opinion regarding f-strings is that an attribute access is ok, or a function call, or a method call, or an indexing operation. Maybe one or two, but more than that, just sue a temporary variable outside the f-string.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. That's definitely something that I'm interested in getting to know, i.e. where others are drawing the line using f-string.

Comment: I completely agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga here. It's the same principal the applies to comprehensions. One, _possible_ two, expressions are fine, but beyond that just makes the resulting code ugly and hard to read. Just create a temporary to hold the result of your expression and use that in the f-string.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianDean. Given that, would you consider the first of my examples OK/readable?

Comment: Eh, to be honest, not really @SuperShoot. Sorry. I'd still say that's a bit much. One way to gauge the readableness of your code is to ask yourself the question, _"if I leave this code for a year or more, and then come back to it, would it be apparent what I'm doing here?"_ In my opinion, it just wouldn't. Plus, extracting the expression into a variables gives you the opportunity to make it clear what a certain expressions represents.

Comment: @ChristianDean No need to be sorry, this is why I'm asking the question. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Interested to know the basis of the downvote? I did put a bit of work into the question and tried to be specific. Too vague? Duplicated? Only asking to be able to format my questions better moving forward. Unexplained downvotes aren't great in that respect.

Comment: Thanks. You'd be surprised at the times I've posted some constructive criticism here and some people take offense to it. As a matter of precaution now, I always try to soften the blow.